# Changing multiple column values at once for a single row in my dataframe

Tags: r

Here is an example of my data

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
                 State = c("StateA", "StateA", NA, "StateB", "StateC", "StateC"),
                 Town = c("Town1", "Town2", NA, "Town4", "Town5", "Town6"),
                 Street = c("StreetX", "StreetY", NA, "StreetQ", "StreetK", "StreetN"))
```

Is there a tidy way to enter the missing data for the row where ID == "C"? e.g. State == "StateB", Town == "Town3", and Street == "StreetZ", for ID == "C" If I had to change values for more observations, I would use some combination of mutate() and case_when(), or mutate_at() as such:

```
df %>%
   mutate(State = ifelse(ID == "C", "StateB", State),
          Town = ifelse(ID == "C", "Town3", Town),
          Street = ifelse(ID == "C", "StreetZ", Street))
```

But this just seems so cumbersome and repetitive for just one record. I tried this:

```
df %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(c("State", "Town", "Street")), ~ifelse(ID == "C", c("StateB", "Town3", "StreetZ"), .)
```

which obviously didn't work or else I wouldn't be here asking how to do it! Or maybe some key/value method might work?

```
c("State" = "StateB", "Town" = "Town3", "Street" = "StreetZ")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to change the value or simply filter to those values?

Comment: I want to change the NA values of 3 (or more) columns for a single row, based on a conditional (may be more than 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new `rows_update` function written for such tasks.

```
library(dplyr)

row <- tibble(ID = 'C', State = 'StateB', Town = 'Town3', Street = 'StreetZ')
result <- rows_update(df, row, by = 'ID')

#  ID  State  Town  Street
#1  A StateA Town1 StreetX
#2  B StateA Town2 StreetY
#3  C StateB Town3 StreetZ
#4  D StateB Town4 StreetQ
#5  E StateC Town5 StreetK
#6  F StateC Town6 StreetN
```

Comment: Seems like you have a typo, instead of ``res`` it should be ``row``.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply! This is great! But now I have another issue as my original post was a simplified version of my actual problem. Can I state an additional conditional? So I want  to replace the row where ID == "C" and State == NA, since there are actually many rows with ID == "C". But where ID == "C" AND State == NA will filter down to a unique row.

Comment: Yes in that case you construct `row` as : `row <- tibble(ID = 'C', State = NA, Town = 'Town3', Street = 'StreetZ')` and `rows_update` as `result <- rows_update(df, row, by = c('ID', 'State'))`